# Time formatting in Python - strptime

Tags: python, strptime

I have a dates stored in a column. But i get errors when i format using strip time.Kindly someone help me with the code. It will be really helpful. Thanks in advance for anyone posting this.

Input:

```py
fbtimenew= facebook['fbtime'][0:2]
fbtimenew
```

Output:

```
0    22:31:28
1    22:03:50
Name: fbtime, dtype: object
```

Input:

```py
for times in fbtimenew:
    print(times)
    times=str(times)
    d = datetime.strptime(times,"%H:%M:%S")
    newtime=d.strftime("%I:%M %p")
newtime
```

Output:

```
22:31:28
22:03:50
```

I am looking for an output

```
10:31 PM
10:03 PM
```

Comment: The first argument `date_string` to `strptime(date_string, format)` is a string to be parsed into a `datetime` object, which should match the format specified in the `format` argument. You're getting the error because the string `'times'` does not match the format `'%H:%M:%S'`.

Comment: Also, read [the documentation of `strptime` and `strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: I think your code is correct! you are probabli just not printing `newtime`

Answer (score 0):

```
for times in fbtimenew:
    newtime=times.strftime("%I:%M %p")
```

It works.